# After update android studio - fail to create new project

Tags: android, android-studio

After updating my Android studio today I created simple project and I got following error that.

```
Error:Could not set process working directory to 'E:\DevelopAndroid\myNewProject': could not set current directory (errno 5)
```

The 'E:\DevelopAndroid\' is exist and the 'myNewProject' folder created. 
But still I can't upload the code to my Git server.

I am not able debug it.

And I don't know what to do.

Comment: Seems like a permission issue? You're working on Linux or Windows ?

Comment: i'm using windows

Comment: Kill the `studio64.exe` process from the task manager and try to open Android studio with `Run as Administrator`

Comment: studio64.exe on helped -  and open as admin is not helping

Comment: you have to clear `.android` folder from your `user` folder.

Comment: found solution?

Answer (score 4):

1. Renaming directory without space
2. delete .idea folder
3. Restart Android Studio

It will work

Comment: Thank you for the restart android studio hint, it worked

Comment: Helped me too !

Answer (score 1):

close current project, delete it and create a new same project, it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

under your project-> look a folder(.idea) delete everything in it. then go to file-> select sync project with gradle files click and let your project sync again

Answer (score 0):

I solve this by assigning full control permissions to the root directory in my Windows 10 machine. In my case `cdm-webservice-v2` is the project directory.

[image: Windows Permission Screen]